# React Native label and value inside CardItem

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm trying to create something like the image below.

[image]

I'm using a Card with CardItem. I was able to create the icon, label and the arrow-forward. How can I set the "value" in the image above the "New York" text in the location? I'm looking for something with the same style.

```
...
import {
  Container, Header, Content, Card,
  CardItem, Text, Right, Icon,
  Left, Body, Title, Button }
from 'native-base';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
...
<CardItem>
    <Left>
        <Entypo name="location" />
        <Text>Location</Text>
    </Left>
    <Right>
        <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
    </Right>
 </CardItem>
```

Comment: `<Right style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>` will align all children of the `Right` component in-line. Then you can add a `<Text>` component for the value and style from there

Comment: It align all the <Right> content to center instead of right side of the Card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a Row component in `native-base`

```
import {
  Container, Header, Content, Card,
  CardItem, Text, Right, Icon,
  Left, Body, Title, Button, Row }


          <CardItem>
              <Left>
                  <Entypo name="location" />
                  <Text>Location</Text>
              </Left>
              <Right>
                  <Row>
                      <Text>USD    </Text>
                      <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
                  </Row>
              </Right>
          </CardItem>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.The odd thing is the spaces after the 'USD' in the <Text> field. Can't we use something like &nbsp? Also, is there a way to set the <Text> style to look like the picture (gray font)

Comment: not sure about that .you can use a marginRight for text component

Comment: <Text style={{color:'grey', marginRight:5}}>USD</Text>